# common solution to $x\equiv 2^{2001}\pmod{4}$ and $x\equiv 14^{2001}\pmod{25}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the common solution to

$x\equiv 2^{2001}\pmod{4}$

and

$x\equiv 14^{2001}\pmod{25}$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $x\equiv0\pmod4,$

and as $\phi(25)=20,2001\equiv1\pmod{20},x\equiv14\pmod{25}$

Now use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Answer (score 0):

First equation is $x\equiv 0\pmod{4}$. So $x=4n$ is the solution to the first equation.

Substitute in second. $4n\equiv 14\pmod{25}\Rightarrow 19\cdot 4n\equiv 19\cdot 14\pmod{25}\Rightarrow n\equiv 16\pmod{25}$

So solution is $x=4n\equiv64\pmod{25}$ and $x=4n\equiv64\pmod{4}$, i.e. $x=4n\equiv 64\pmod{100}$

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to calculate $14^{2001}\pmod{100}$

As $(14^{2001},100)=4,$ let us calculate $14^{2001-2}\pmod{\dfrac{100}4}$ i.e., $14^{1999}\pmod{25}$

Now, $\phi(25)=20$ and $1999\equiv-1\pmod{20}\implies14^{1999}\equiv14^{-1}\pmod{25}$

As $14\cdot9\equiv1\pmod{25},14^{-1}\equiv9\implies14^{1999}\equiv9\pmod{25}$

$\implies14^{1999}\cdot14^2\equiv9\cdot14^2\pmod{25\cdot14^2}$

As $100\mid25\cdot14^2,$

$14^{1999+2}\equiv9\cdot14^2\pmod{100}\equiv9(-4)\equiv-36\equiv64$

Comment: You answered two times! :P

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi, Have you noticed the difference in the approaches?

Comment: Yes, I did notice.